# How to copy data from dataset to a type dataset using automapper?

Tags: .net, vb.net, automapper

I am trying to copy data from a standard Dataset to a Type Dataset (XSD) of same table structure. I want to use `Automapper` to do that one. So how can I do that using automapper?

Answer (score 0):

AutoMapper doesn't support this.  You'll have to code this by hand.  However, if you can extract some conventions, you may be able to use the DataSet metadata (DataColumn etc.) to automatically do this, without coding each table/column by hand.